# Gem for counting amount of touches of items of certain model in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Yo!

Is there a gem for rails, which allows the count of an item of a certain model being touched (updated)? For example, I am having a model `invitation_links` which holds invitation links that users can use. Whenever an invitation link is used, it should be touched and the count should go up +1.

Hope you understand what I want, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This only existing tool for that is [Counter Cache](https://scoutapm.com/blog/how-to-start-using-counter-caches-in-rails) I would say.